# SQL Server to PostgreSQL migration - SSMS - export constraints

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, ssms

I am trying to export a database from SQL Server to PostgreSQL. I found the export data utility in SQL Server Management Studio very handy. I am able to migrate the tables along with the values in it. But the primary key, foreign key, and other table constraints are not moved. My database is huge with about 600 tables, so manual scripting is very tedious. Is there a way to make SSMS migrate the column constraints as well?

Answer (score 0):

I've just finished a SQL Server to Postgres migration on a project and I used Navicat to do the initial migration, was very easy. Navicat is available for a short trial period which is handy too though it's good enough to warrant buying if you like SSMS for sql server.